# Android 11 device Not showing badge count

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-launcher, android-notification-bar

I am showing an android app to show the badge count on the app launcher icon. Tried in a different version but it's not working on Android 11. May I know, is there anything new API for the same on android 11?

Code I used is given below :

```
 scheduleNotification(getNotification( "Submitted Successfully" ) , 100 ) ;

  private Notification getNotification (String content) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, default_notification_channel_id ) ;
        builder.setContentTitle( "Notification" ) ;
        builder.setContentText(content) ;
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. ic_launcher_foreground ) ;
        builder.setAutoCancel( true ) ;
        builder.setChannelId( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ) ;
        builder.setNumber(8);
        writeLog("Home Screen -->"+ Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].
                getLineNumber()+" --> Offline Submission Locally Notified ");

        return builder.build() ;
    }

private void scheduleNotification (Notification notification , int delay) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( this, MyNotificationPublisher. class ) ;
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MyNotificationPublisher. NOTIFICATION_ID , 1 ) ;
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MyNotificationPublisher. NOTIFICATION , notification) ;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent. getBroadcast ( this, 0 , notificationIntent , 
        PendingIntent. FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ) ;
        long futureInMillis = SystemClock. elapsedRealtime () + delay ;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context. ALARM_SERVICE ) ;
        assert alarmManager != null;
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager. ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP , futureInMillis , pendingIntent) ;
      
    }
```

MyNotificationPublisher  class looks :

```
public class MyNotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id" ;
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification" ;
    public static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ="10001";
    public void onReceive (Context context , Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context. NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ;
        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra( NOTIFICATION ) ;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION. SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES. O ) {
            int importance = NotificationManager. IMPORTANCE_HIGH ;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID , "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME" , importance) ;
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel) ;
        }
        int id = intent.getIntExtra( NOTIFICATION_ID , 0 ) ;
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(id , notification) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any update on this?